# If condition selects all checkboxes

Tags: jquery

Select only the ones that has attribute set to `checked="checked"` but it selects all.

```
<input class="chxbx" type="checkbox" checked="checked"> 
<input class="chxbx" type="checkbox"> 
<input class="chxbx" type="checkbox">
```

jQuery:

```
$(".chxbx").each(function(i, e){
  if($(".chxbx").prop("checked", true)){
   // this should select only the the input tag with 
   //checked="checked" but it selects all checkboxes
  }     
})
```

Comment: What is the question? I think you need `$(".chxbx:checked")` see [`:checked` Selector](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/)

Comment: Hi Satpal, if condition selects all checkboxes. In html only first input tag is checked and jquery if condition needs to show that only the first tag has checked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not using `.each` correctly.

Should be:

```
$(".chxbx").each(function(){

  if($(this).is(":checked")){

   // this should select only the the input tag with 
   //checked="checked" but it selects all checkboxes
  }     
});
```

Or alternatively:

```
$(".chxbx:checked").each(function(){

 // this should select only the the input tag with 
 //checked="checked" but it selects all checkboxes
});
```